# Facebook API - Adding a new photo (Javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Am trying to **add a new photo along with some text and a url attached to the image** to my current website on a button click. (See below for image). I want the output to be exactly like that.
This button click will prompt a popup similar to the share feature provided by Facebook.

This was the code that i tried, but no reponse came.

```
FB.api(
    "/me/photos",
    "POST", {
        "url": "http://localhost/meisterdish/web/images/logo.png",
        "message" : "Test text here"
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    }
);
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

**TLDR:** Adding a photo to the wall, via API.

**PS:** I don't want a sharing on the feed feature(Feed API). I already know that.

**PSS:** Got an error : Object {message: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", type: "OAuthException", code: 200}

Comment: Do you have facebook app for your site?

Comment: Does your app have the relevant permission from the user? And log the response to console in any case, and see what it contains. (And keep in mind, that the `message` has to be entered by the user of your app, your app is not allowed to specify it for them.)

Comment: @CBroe Yeh, have an error : Object {message: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", type: "OAuthException", code: 200}

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: By asking the user for the relevant permission before trying to publish a photo on their behalf.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, but how do i do that? Is that an option within the FB app settings?

Comment: No, you do that by implementing Facebook login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80654/discussion-between-nevin-madhukar-k-and-cbroe).

Comment: There isn’t much more to discuss – you need to implement Facebook login and ask the user for permission. And if you don’t know the first thing about how to do that – then it’s time you start reading the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use "feed" API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

You need to provide "message" and "link(as picture)" to the API

Comment: Please refer to my question again.. i don't need the "feed" API.

Comment: Then what you need? Your example is image is similar to "feed".

Comment: I think you miss something in here. I created this with feed API similar to your example image: http://i.imgur.com/TBNSfNy.png

Comment: Yes, that's not what i wanted. 
What i want is an image added to the wall as shown in the question.